# Can scala syntatic sugar make a congruence mod n?

Tags: scala, syntax, equivalence

Consider 2+7 == 3+6 (mod 5).  Can you some how use scala syntactic sugar to achieve the same in scala code?

Keep in mind that 2+7 and 3+6 are regular scala Int so overriding the + or == to be mod 5 doesn't work.  I'm actually interested in more complex congruences on algebras A.  I could do `A.congruent(a,b)`, and write that with some nice symbols like  `A.~(a,b)`, but I am interested in `a == b (A)` or `a ==(A) b` or perhaps `A(a == b)`.  Something where the congruence appears inbetween the terms a and b.

The bottom line of my struggles is that the congruence is defined for type `A`, and `a`,`b` are some elements passed to `A` but not actually of type `A`.  E.g. `A` might be a group of matrices and the congruence is if individual matrices `a` and `b` differ by a scalar i.e. `a*b^-1=sI_n`.  In particular, `a`, `b` will live inside of many groups and the congruence will change based on that. So I it isn't possible to simply add a reference within `a` and `b` back to `A`.

Some how the right solution seems to be the mathematical one, label the equivalence with `A` not the variables `a` and `b`.  Yet scala syntactic sugar may not have such a sweetness in mind.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: To clarify context, I'm happy for a solution that just tricks the REPL.  If a user is writing their own actual code then prefix notation like `A.cong(a,b)` wont throw them.  But students and teachers who don't code much would prefer infix style found in books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
implicit class ModEquals(a: Int) {
    def %%(n: Int) = new { def ===(b: Int) = (a - b) % n == 0 }
}
```

Usage:

```
7 %% 3 === 10
```

This solution enriches `Int`s with a `%%` method that takes the congruence. In this example, it's just modulu, but this can easily be extended to anything. The returned object is a class that has an `===` method defined to implements the equality check.

Comment: Clever, the implicit class idea is the hint I needed, though it seems easier for my intention to replace `def %%` etc. with `def ~(b:Int) = (a-b)%n == 0`, so one can simply write `n=5; (2+7)~(4+10)` (true) and changing n, `n=7; (2+7)~(4+10)` false.  And as @thesamet notes it adapts easily to generic congruences. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.languageFeature.implicitConversions
import scala.languageFeature.reflectiveCalls

case class ModuloArg(list: List[Int]) {
  assert(list.size > 1)

  def ==%%?(m: Int) = {
    val hm = list.head % m
    list.tail.filter(i => (i % m) != hm).isEmpty
  }

  def ::%%(n: Int) = ModuloArg(n :: list)

}

implicit class ModuloArgOps(i: Int) {
  def ::%%(n: Int) = ModuloArg(n :: i :: Nil)
}
```

Now, you can use these to check modulo equality,

```
// 4 == 10 (mod 3) 
scala> val mod3Equal4And10 = 4 ::%% 10 ==%%? 3
// mod3Equal4And10: Boolean = true

// 4 == 11 (mod 3) 
scala> val mod3Equal4And11 = 4 ::%% 11 ==%%? 3
//mod3Equal4And11: Boolean = false

// 4 == 10 == 13 == 16 (mod 3)
scala> val mod3Equal4And10And13And16 = 4 ::%% 10 ::%% 13 ::%% 16 ==%%? 3
// mod3Equal4And10And13And16: Boolean = true
```